# LimeSurvey is clearing answers when skipping questions groups

Tags: limesurvey

I have a survey set up that has preloaded answers that user edit. For example I preload their contact info and they edit where needed. 
My problem is that I have a question at the beginning of the survey that if the user answers "yes" to it skips to the last question of the survey. When it does that, its also clearing all the preloaded answers in the survey which I do not want to happen.
I am skipping the question groups using a relevance equation similar to this -

compvisit.NAOK == "N"

Does anyone know how to make it to where it will not clear the preloaded questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the file application/config/config.php to add  `'deletenonvalues' => 1,` on config array.

See my answer here : https://www.limesurvey.org/forum/design-issues/112105-issue-with-skipping-questions-without-clearing-them#156833